# Open an application from another one

Tags: qooxdoo

Let's say I have an app (www.myappsmenu.com) and after selecting some info, input user and password, etc. I need to open www.myapp1.com or www.myapp2.com depending data introduced, all apps made with qooxdoo standalone and different web hosting.
How to open the second app and then close the first one ?

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, this isn't really qooxdoo-specific. You can redirect to a new URL with something like

```
window.location.href = "http://www.myapp1.com";
```

You can put that in a qooxdoo event listener, e.g.,

```
button = new qx.ui.form.Button("MyApp1");
container.add(button);
button.addListener(
  "execute",
  function(e)
  {
    window.location.href = "http://www.myapp1.com";
  },
  this);
```

This will redirect to the new page when the button is pressed.

Comment: Derrell, can you give me a hint on how to pass a value from app1 to app2? I tried cookie, storage and nop I can't make it work. I need to send/pass some selected data from 1st app to the other one.

Comment: Never mind, I got it with bom.history() thanks a lot anyway.